# problem reading binary file in python running on multiple processor

Tags: mpi4py

I am running my python code in parallel using mpi4py

mpirun -np 2 python main.py

However when it starts reading a binary file produced by another fortran code I get the following error

scipy.io._fortran.FortranFormattingError: End of file in the middle of a record

However if I run it in serial

mpirun -np 1 python main.py

the program completes successfully